# Who can help me identify this handwritten-looking script font?

Tags: font-identification

Can anyone tell me which font is used on the card below?

Thank you very much!

[image: handwritten script font]

Comment: Hello kathleen, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. Have you tried the image-based font identifiers [What the Font](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) and [Identifont](http://www.identifont.com/)? Please try those as well, maybe then you can answer your own question. Thanks!

Comment: We have a collection of font identification resources, and it is a good idea to try that first. Edit your question and let us know what you have tried without luck. Always good to show a little effort, and chances of getting a good answer increases. http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info

Comment: What if it is hand-written.

Comment: I don't think it's hand-written - the 'm' glyphs are the same. [This font](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/emily-lime/carolyna-pro-black/) isn't the answer, but it's in the same ballpark. I found that one just by scrolling through MyFonts' handwritten tag results for a bit.

Answer (score 9):

The font in the image is: [Cantoni Bold](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/debi-sementelli/cantoni/bold/) and all of the glyphs are there.

The rest of the Cantoni fonts can be found [here](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/debi-sementelli/cantoni/).

[image: Cantoni font sets]

To  verify: [Click here](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/debi-sementelli/cantoni/bold/glyphs.html?vid=624380&render=old) and look for the numbers located beneath the letters.

Comment: Nice! Good find!

Comment: That's pretty cool that you found it Brian, I tried but failed! :)